# Как центровать сайт HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Привет я сделал вот такой вот шаблон но когда его масштабировать он остается на месте а я хочу сделать так чтоб он уходил в центр как в любых известных сайтах кто знает как отпишите

Я много где по гуглил и почти все писали написать margin: 0; но как и где оно применяется я не знаю можете пожалуйста объяснить детально в комментариях

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: задаете контейнер нужной ширины и в стилях прописываете ему `margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте все в `div` в id *center*. В css  пропишите

```
    div#center {
width: ширина сайта; 
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```